# O que significa e como usar o valor (Number)n+(Number) na propriedade nth-child()?

Tags: html, css

Eu já vi vários exemplos usando a propriedade `nth-child()` com valores como um número para selecionar um determinado elemento ou selecionar elementos pares e ímpares com os valores `even` e `odd`, mas eu vi que tem como selecionar um elemento com essa sintaxe como valor na propriedade `nth-child()`:

**Sintaxe:**

```
:nth-child((Number)n+(Number)) {
    property: value;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        p:nth-child(2n+4) {
            background: black;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Esse é um parágrafo.</p>
    <p>Esse é um parágrafo.</p>
    <p>Esse é um parágrafo.</p>
    <p>Esse é um parágrafo.</p>
    <p>Esse é um parágrafo.</p>
    <p>Esse é um parágrafo.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse valor me deixou muito confuso o que quer dizer esse valor `2n+4`? e como usar ele?

Answer (score 0):

**An+B**

Representa elementos cuja posição numérica em uma série de irmãos corresponda ao padrão An+B, o qual será aplicado a todo número maior ou igual a zero (ou seja, começando do zero). O índice do primeiro elemento é 1. Ambos os valores A e B devem ser  (inteiros).

*HTML*

```
<h3><code>span:nth-child(2n+1)</code>, SEM um
<code>&lt;em&gt;</code> entre os elementos filhos.</h3>
<p>Os filhos 1, 3, 5 e 7 são selecionados.</p>
<div class="primeiro">
  <span>Span 1!</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <span>Span 3!</span>
  <span>Span 4</span>
  <span>Span 5!</span>
  <span>Span 6</span>
  <span>Span 7!</span>
</div>

<br>

<h3><code>span:nth-child(2n+1)</code>, COM um
   <code>&lt;em&gt;</code> entre os elementos filhos.</h3>
<p>Os filhos 1, 5 e 7 são selecionados.<br>
   O 3 está incluído na contagem por ser um filho, mas não é
   selecionado porque ele não é um <code>&lt;span&gt;</code>.</p>
<div class="segundo">
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <em>Este é um `em`.</em>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
</div>

<br>

<h3><code>span:nth-of-type(2n+1)</code>, COM um
   <code>&lt;em&gt;</code> entre os elementos filhos.</h3>
<p>Os filhos 1, 4, 6 e 8 são selecionados.<br>
   O 3 não está incluso na contagem nem é selecionado porque ele é um <code>&lt;em&gt;</code>, 
   não um <code>&lt;span&gt;</code>, e <code>nth-of-type</code> seleciona apenas os
   filhos desse último tipo. O <code>&lt;em&gt;</code> é completamente
   pulado e ignorado.</p>
<div class="terceiro">
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <em>Este é um `em`.</em>
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span!</span>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span,
div em {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.primeiro span:nth-child(2n+1),
.segundo span:nth-child(2n+1),
.terceiro span:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

fonte e resultado do código acima: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child